# How to show div on textbox control using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am stucked into an issue,as i have captured the mouseover event on textbox.Here is code of mouseOvering;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("dijit_form_Textarea_0").attachEvent("onmouseover",function(){
document.getElementById("div_1_1_1").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("dijit_form_Textarea_0").setAttribute("title",'Hello World');

});
```

This code works fine and shows tooltip when mouse is over on particular textbox.
Now i want to show div on mouseOvering instead of showing tooltip.

How can i accomplish this task,can anyone assist me?

Comment: using mouseover , mouseout events 

and the offsetLeft and offsetTop of the textbox the you can place the div style position absolute in the place y define after knowing the left and top of the textbox on the events i have told you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a div with the tip you want, set its position to 'absolute' and set its left/top to the place u want it to appear

see an example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/x8u8K/)

Comment: Hi,
how can i do this ?can you provide me a little more detail about this.

Comment: ill make you a demo fiddle in a minute

Comment: Hi i am waiting for your response

Comment: sorry for late reply, i have updated my answer with an example:

Comment: if my answered helped you solve your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the green V on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

The `attachEvent()` is used for IE browsers, use `addEventListener()` to other browsers(FF and Chrome).

```
document.getElementById("dijit_form_Textarea_0").addEventListener("mouseover",
```

For IE and Other browsers you could do like this.

```
window.onload=function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("dijit_form_Textarea_0");
    if (div.addEventListener) {
        div.addEventListener('mouseover', changeStyle);
    } else if (div.attachEvent) {
        div.attachEvent("onmouseover", changeStyle);
    }

    function changeStyle(){
        document.getElementById("div_1_1_1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("dijit_form_Textarea_0").setAttribute("title",'Hello World');
    }
);
```

Comment: I am asking about how to show div instead of tooltip.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let say your div have id="mydiv"

```
<div I'd="mydiv"></div>
```

In the place where you entered the code for showing the title, put the following

```
$('#mydiv').show(); 

 And you want to hide the div, use

$("#mydiv").hide();
```

Comment: op did not tag jQuery.

Comment: But it is a lot easier and they work together that if at all there is difference.

Comment: I just wanted to use JS,no JQuery